# autoscroll a div to the bottom on adding new content to the div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that takes new content as shown from a text area as shown

```
<div style="overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden; height:296px;" id="container"></div>
```

when the div fills to the maximum height, I am trying to achieve that the div should show new contents by scrolling down automatically and this is my attempt

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                        ....
                    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = contents;
                    //this is the code I am trying to use to make it scroll automatically down when new content is added
                    document.getElementById('container').scrollBottom = y;

                } else {
                    alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
```

contents in the div is not scrolling down automatically when the div reaches 296px. Please what could be wrong?

Comment: this is just a code snippet .. how can we help you with this. what is *y* ?? what is *contents*, what is *json.length*?? The "else" statement after "for" ??

Comment: <div style="overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden; height:296px;" id="container"></div>

Comment: what is the value of each in your JS code ? what is in your markup has nothing to do with that, it can only give us a clue nothing more .. even then the clue to whats the value of *y* is nowhere in your markup

Comment: My downvote is because of this - "Help others reproduce the problem"  - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: okay. Good to know you are the one but the young shall surely grow someday.

Comment: I was expecting you to know that this code does html injection

Comment: document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = contents;

Comment: yes or no.........................

Comment: then this div populates the injected html >>>>>>>>>> <div style="overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden; height:296px;" id="container"></div>

Comment: As some point, this div fills up and when new contents are added, it becomes hidden and so you have to scroll down to view

Comment: which led to this code >>>>>>>> //this is the code I am trying to use to make it scroll automatically down when new content is added
                    document.getElementById('container').scrollBottom = y;

Comment: html injection is obvious but inject with WHAT is the actual question ? you would have declared the value of *contents* variable as `var contents = "some value here"` & `var y = "296"` or `json = { ... }` where are all these in your code ??

Comment: Or even better .. just provide a working Fiddle with your problem. Simple ! not interested in arguing with a kid. See if you can provide a working Fiddle replicating your issue.

Comment: Thanks i know I am a kid! If you look you would have seen four dots signifying "some codes here". Anyway check to see my answer

Comment: Its obvious that my question was sentimentally downvoted

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem using this

$("#container").scrollTop($("#container")[0].scrollHeight);

the above replaced this:

document.getElementById('container').scrollBottom = y;

And my problem is solved.